# Compute if orthogonal through Point P intersects a line segment defined by its endpoints

Tags: dart, geometry

Assume a line is defined through its endpoints `begin` and `end`.
Suppose P is another point

[image]

**I'm in search of a method, which returns true iff. the orthogonal of Line(A,B) through target cuts Line(A,B) between A and B.**

This method computes the length of a line:

```
  static double lengthOfLine(Offset a, Offset b ) {
    double length = math.sqrt( ( b.dx - a.dx )*( b.dx - a.dx ) + ( b.dy - a.dy ) * ( b.dy - a.dy ) );
    return length;
  }
```

And this function the distance between `target` and the **indefinite long** line defined by `begin` and `end`:

```
  static double shortestDistance(Offset begin, Offset end, Offset target) {

    double legnthOfLine = lengthOfLine( begin, end );

    double a = end.dy - begin.dy;
    double b = begin.dx - end.dx;
    double c = end.dx * begin.dy - begin.dx * end.dy;

    double q = a * target.dx + b * target.dy + c;
    if ( 0.0 > q ) {
      q = -1.0 * q;
    }

    return q / legnthOfLine;

  }
```

I just want to know, if the othogonal relative to `Line(begin, end)` through `target` cuts `Line(begin, end)` within `begin` and `end`.

Comment: You could compute the intersection between the two lines and then check if the x-coordinate of the intersection is between the x-coordinates of `begin` and `end`. (Or the y-coordinates; it doesn't matter.) (And remember that orthogonal lines have slopes that are negative reciprocals of each other.)

Comment: @jamesdlin Good ide. Unfortunately, it's a bit late for me today. Will grab my old math book. One could conceptually this: Image a circle around end that passes target and a circle around end that passes target. Using the diameters of both circles, you may construct the shadow of target at the oder side of Line(begin, end). Then compute the cutting point of Line(begin, end) and Line(target, shadow of target).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work?

```
static bool perp_intersects_segment(Offset start, Offset end,  Offset target ) {

    double start_end_x = end.dx - start.dx;
    double start_end_y = end.dy - start.dy;
    double dot_product = start_end_x * (target.dx - end.dx) 
                       + start_end_y * (target.dy - end.dy);

    dot_product = ( start_end_x * (target.dx - start.dx) 
                  + start_end_y * (target.dy - start.dy)
                  ) * dot_product;

    return ( dot_product <= 0.0 );

}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you, futurologist!

Comment: A question from a non native speaker: Why name it perp?

Comment: @SteAp perpendicular intersects segment... I just wrote whatever came to my mind... oh an yes... bool :)... thanks for correcting it